# Java collision check doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, lwjgl, collision

I am programming a Game in Java.
I am using LWJGL as engine because it seems to fit my needs.

I just implemented the main menu and I wrote a class for the Menu Elements,
after that I wrote the code to display the elements at the center of the screen and then I tried to write some code that checks if the mouse hovers over a button.

Sadly it doesn't work as expected.
The collision check seems to be very fucked up.

Hope you can help :)

Here is my code to render the menu and check for a collision:

```
public static void RenderMenu()
{
    int LineHeight = 45;
    int StartOffset = (Display.getHeight() / 2) - ((elements.length * LineHeight) / 2);
    int current = 0;

    int MouseX = Mouse.getX();
    int MouseY = Mouse.getY();

    boolean TitleDrawn = false;

    for (MenuElement elem : elements)
    {
        Engine.DrawStringCentered(elem.Text, StartOffset + (LineHeight * current));

        elem.X = (Display.getWidth() / 2) - (elem.GetWidth() / 2);
        elem.Y = StartOffset + (LineHeight * current);

        if ((MouseX >= elem.X && MouseX <= elem.X + elem.GetWidth()) &&
            (MouseY >= elem.Y && MouseY <= elem.Y + elem.GetHeight()))
        {
            Engine.DrawTitle(elem.Text);
            TitleDrawn = true;
        }

        current++;
    }

    if (!TitleDrawn) Engine.DrawTitle("Backsteine");
}
```

The collision check is very simple.
It just checks if the mouse is inside the bounds of the element.

I don't understand why it doesn't work

// UPDATE
I finally figured it out.
The Y coordinate was flipped for some reason.

I fixed it by calculating the Y value as followed:
int MouseY = Display.getHeight() - Mouse.getY();

Thanks to Marcel Puyat :D

Comment: I have recommended that this question be migrated to gamedev.stackexchange.com as I feel it will get a better response there.

Comment: What have you tried? For UI programs debugging may be a difficult unless you do it from a different machine. Did you at least try logging variable values ?

Comment: I am using LWJGL. It should handle the mouse correctly
I will try to log the values now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this could be off in your code:

```
(MouseY >= elem.Y && MouseY <= elem.Y + elem.GetHeight())
```

Y-values increase as they go down and decrease as they go up (i.e. your origin is at the top left of the screen.) So a collision would be when your mouse is LESS than elem.Y and GREATER than elem.Y + elem.GetHeight().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just subtracted the Mouse Y value from the Screen height and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the X cords is also backwards. If I was in your shoes I would try putting in cords and see if that works. It also could be you don't have a mouse listener or it is not running right. If you need help with a mouse listener check out The Java Hub on youtube and look at his pong game menu. He uses the same concept.

Comment: Thanks! :D
The X coordinate isn't flipped in my case, but the Y coord is flipping.